# Passing null string to function as an argument

Tags: c++

What is the right way of passing NULL string to a function without creating a variable? 
I see compilation error with following code and I don't want to change the definition. Also may have to make change to string so don't want to mark it a constant type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void
myfunc(int i,  string &my) {
   if (my.empty()) {
      cout << "Empty" << endl;
   } else {
      cout << "String is " << my <<endl;
   }
}
int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Test string");
  myfunc(1, str1);
  std::string str2 ("");
  myfunc(2, "");
  return 0;
}`
```

my1.cpp:18: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a temporary of type ‘const char*’
my1.cpp:6: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘void myfunc(int, std::string&)
’

Following compiles but I dont want to create local variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void
myfunc(int i,  string &my) {
   if (my.empty()) {
      cout << "Empty" << endl;
   } else {
      cout << "String is " << my <<endl;
   }
}
int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Test string");
  myfunc(1, str1);
  std::string str2 ("");
  myfunc(2, str2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are passing by reference means passing the address of the variable not the value. if you want pass by value.

Comment: References are usually implemented as a pointer in disguise, but this isn't required by the standard. What **IS** required is that the reference actually reference a proper object.

Comment: @Raindrop7, Do we have a way by which we can pass reference to string without creating an object?

Comment: the only way is to make it `const`.

Comment: Important fun fact: `""` isn't a `std::string`. It's a `const char *`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 what compiler does when it see "" is passed to a function expecting a reference to a string? Does it internally pass a null string object?

Comment: @Tectrendz it does the exact same thing as when you pass `"some string"`. Syntactically there is no difference. They are both string literals. One has 0 characters, the other has 11 characters, but that is completely irrelevant to the type system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're asking the impossible  (by over-constraining the problem).   Passing `""` to your function requires the caller to convert `""` to a `string` i.e. to create a temporary of type `string`.  Passing a temporary by reference is only permitted if the function accepts a `const` reference.

Comment: @user4581301 actually it is a `char const[1]`

Comment: I bow to the more-correct interpretation.

Comment: please read a book about "passing by value vs by reference and pointer" instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution here is to have an overload that doesn't have the string parameter.

```
void myfunc(int i,  string &my) {
      cout << "String is " << my <<endl;
}

void myfunc(int i) {
   cout << "Empty" << endl;
}
```

```
int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Test string");
  myfunc(1, str1);
  myfunc(2);
}
```

This is the most simple and clear solution that conveys exactly your intent and functionality.

You shouldn't try to do it your way because if you want to modify the argument then the parameter should be "non-const reference" and so it cannot bind to temporaries. Thus you can't pass a string literal to it.

---

If you want to make it explicit that you don't pass a string, you could create a tag ala `nullptr`, although I do not recommend the extra complication when the above variant is clear and understood by everybody at first glance.

```
struct no_string_tag_t {};
constexpr no_string_tag_t no_string_tag;

void myfunc(int i,  string &my) {
      cout << "String is " << my <<endl;
}

void myfunc(int i, no_string_tag_t) {
   cout << "Empty" << endl;
}
```

```
int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Test string");
  myfunc(1, str1);
  myfunc(2, no_string_tag);
}
```

---

If you really want a single function, then the semantically correct version would have an optional reference.

```
auto foo(int i, std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> my)
{
    if (my)
        cout << "String is " << my <<endl;
    else
        cout << "no string" << endl;

}
```

```
int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Test string");
  myfunc(1, str1);
  myfunc(2, std::nullopt);
}
```

---

If you want to keep the function signature and still be able to pass it a temporary, then you are out of luck. `C++` has a safety feature in that it does not allow a non-const lreferece to bind to a temporary. The reason for this restriction is that attempting to modify a temporary via a lreference would most likely be bug and not the programmers's intent since the temporary dies out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a temporary to a non-const reference parameter. The object, being temporary, will be destroyed as soon as the function returns. Any changes that the function did to the object would be lost.

If you want to have the chance to modify the string, you can take the string by const reference and return a modified string.

```
string myfunc( int i, string const &s );
:
str1 = myfunc( 1, str1 );
auto result2 = myfunc( 2, "" );
```

Your other option is to use a pointer to a string that can be null.

```
void myfunc( int i, string *s ) {
    if (!s) {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "String is " << *s <<endl;
    }
}

myfunc( 1, &str1 );
myfunc( 2, nullptr );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ommit 1 or more arguments in functions calls as long those argument(s) are the last ones in the order or the args prototyped in that function.

You can also give a padron value if the argument is ommited when calling the function.

```
using namespace std;

void sTest(int a, string x ="TEST", int z=0);

void sTest(int a, string x, int z)
 {
    cout << x;
 }

int main() 
{   
   sTest(5); // displayed “TEST”
}
```